# Divide and Conquer to solve the power of a number, runtime analysis with master theorem

Tags: algorithm, runtime, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

I implemented a divide and conquer algorithm to calculate the power of a number:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Result: " + pow(2, 1));
    System.out.println("Result: " + pow(2, 9));
    System.out.println("Result: " + pow(2, 8));
    System.out.println("Result: " + pow(2, 0));
}

private static int pow(int n, int pow) {
    if(pow == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if(pow > 2) {
        int leftPow;
        int rightPow;

        if(pow % 2 != 0) {
            leftPow = pow/2;
            rightPow = pow/2+1;
        } else {
            leftPow = pow/2;
            rightPow = leftPow;
        }

        return pow(n, leftPow) * pow(n, rightPow);
    } else {
        if(pow == 1) {
            return n;
        } else {
            return n * n;
        }
    }
}
```

My method seems to work, since the output is:

```
Result: 2
Result: 512
Result: 256
Result: 1
```

Now Iam trying to determine the runtime of my algorithm using the Master-Theorem:

[image]

I assume, that

[image], since the recursive call appears two times,

[image], since Iam creating two subproblems out of one problem

and [image], since combining the results takes constant time.

The watershed constant ([image]) should be [image].

With these values, I assume that the first rule of the Theorem holds:
[image], with [image], since [image].

Therefore the runtime should be:
[image].

Iam quite unsure about this result, since I never had the case [image].

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: You are aware that your implementation does not save any multiplication compared to the naive implementation `n*n*n*n...*n`? You could if you avoid recalculation of the same powers again and again e.g. by storing them in a shared data-structure.

Comment: @MrSmith42 yes I do know that there is no performance gain with this implementation. My goal was only to implement it with a divide and conquer approach since this was the given task.

Comment: @MrSmith42, if I would store results into memory to look them up later, would this be a dynamic approach?

Comment: You could call it dynamic approach. Even if it is a very simple version in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should notice that the complexity will be explained based on the `pow`. So, `n` in your analysis means `pow` not `n` variable in your program.

Second, as the number of computations such as comparison and multiplying is constant (less than 10 for your program), so `f(n) = \Theta(1)` and you can write it `f(n) = 1` here.

Therefore, the  complexity is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1` (you can see Akra-Bazzi method too), and `T(n) = \Theta(n)`.

Comment: Yes, youre right, my `n` should be called `pow`.
Thank you for your answer, I will have a look at the Akra-Bazzi method!